# Get cost value of chosen shipping method at checkout of Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

In functions.php of my child theme I have custom script like this:

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process1');
function my_custom_checkout_field_process1() {

//do something

}

To do some calculations I need to get the cost of chosen shipping method. How to do that?

[image: I need to get value of 4.82]

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
$cart  = WC()->cart;
$total = __( 'Free!', 'woocommerce' );
if ( 0 < $cart->get_shipping_total() ) {
    if ( $cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
        $total = $cart->shipping_total + $cart->shipping_tax_total;
    } else {
        $total = $cart->shipping_total;
    }
}
```